# Attempting DateTime conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a column as per below in datetime format and this column is defined as `nvarchar(max)` datatype as I loaded it from an Excel file.

I need to convert it to `datetime` datatype - if someone can please help to do it. Thanks

```
ReportDateTime
-------------------
11/01/2019 08:27:00
25/01/2019 11:48:00
```

I tried to load different way but did not succeed.

Comment: Google [sql server convert varchar to datetime](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+convert+varchar+to+datetime+site:stackoverflow.com). Try it out and if it does not work come back and let us know what is not working.

Comment: Is 11/01  January 11th?

Answer (score 1):

One option is `Set DateFormat DMY`  prior to the load from excel

**Example**

```
Set Dateformat DMY

Declare @YourTable Table ([ReportDateTime] Datetime)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('11/01/2019 08:27:00')
,('25/01/2019 11:48:00')
 
Select * 
from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
ReportDateTime
2019-01-11 08:27:00.000
2019-01-25 11:48:00.000
```

**EDIT - Or if data loaded as a string**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ReportDateTime] varchar(50))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('11/01/2019 08:27:00')
,('25/01/2019 11:48:00')
 
Select *
      ,AsDateTime = try_convert(datetime, [ReportDateTime],103)
from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
ReportDateTime          AsDateTime
11/01/2019 08:27:00     2019-01-11 08:27:00.000
25/01/2019 11:48:00     2019-01-25 11:48:00.000
```

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for prompt and perfect answer for my question. U R ROCK..

Comment: @user3142432 Don't forget you can add culture to convert   try_convert(datetime, [ReportDateTime],103)   --- notice the 103